# Proof of the projection formula (for cohomology of $\mathbf{P}V$)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, etale-cohomology

Let $V\to X$ be a vector bundle (over say a scheme).

Then the cohomology of its projectivisation is
$$\text{H}^*(\mathbf{P}V)\ =\ \text{H}^*(X)[t]/(t^{n+1}+c_1(V)t^n+\cdots+c_n(V))$$
as an algebra, where $n$ is the rank of $V$. Here $\text{H}^*$ is $\ell$-adic/singular/de Rham/... cohomology/stable homotopy theory/... etc. (any proof of this will surely only use formal properties of $\text{H}^*$ so it doesn't matter which cohomology theory you use).

What is a good reference for the proof of this fact? What are the main ideas in the proof?

Comment: I would try Fulton, Intersection theory

Comment: As far as I can tell it's tricky to make the Noetherian induction step of his proof of Thm 3.3 work for cohomology rather than Chow homology.